# how to send command to telnet which is running on non standard port in perl

Tags: perl, daemon, telnet

I have one daemon process written in perl which listens custom commands on port 8622.

Now I want to write a client program which can call daemon process using telnet command. client program must grab the output and process further based on received output.

I don't have any username password for telnet which is running on port 8622.

Following is my code for client program

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -wl 
use Net::Telnet;

$port = 8622;
$IP = '127.0.0.1';
$cmd = "CSDD"; #command to send

 $telnet = new Net::Telnet ( Timeout=>5, port=>$port, Errmode=>'die',Prompt => '/\$ $/i');
$telnet->open($IP);
#$telnet->login('',''); 

print $telnet->cmd($cmd);
$telnet->close;
exit;
```

Daemon process receives the command but it keeps running in infinite loop even there is no condition check for anything.

Daemon process works correctly if I run telnet from command prompt.

I hope I have explained correctly with my poor English.
I very new to perl so please help me out.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Is the prompt really a dollar sign followed by a space?  Try using `'/\$ ?$/i'` or other variations.  There are `print` and `waitfor` methods which provide a lower level interface than `cmd`, presumably they'll work.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion now daemon process accepts the command sent by client program correctly, but I am not able to grab the data sent to client program from daemon process.
I am catching in following way ... 
Thanks once again for your prompt reply
[code]
$telnet->waitfor('/^$/');
$telnet->print($cmd);
$result = $telnet->waitfor('/^$/');
print $result;
[code]
It just outputs `1`
How I can grab the data sent by daemon process?
Is above code correct?
Thanks once again for your prompt answer :)

Comment: More info on Daemon process
daemon process accepts the socket connection from client program and then it sends data back to client program as 

[code]print SOCK "this is the result"; [code]